# How to change Time Format from 24 Hours to 12 in MVC View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to change my time from

> 06/08/2015 15:55:31

to

> 06/08/2015 03:55 PM

Here is my code.

```
<td >
 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem =>item.Received) //Date Column
 @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.Received, new { @class = "fieldName" })
</td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decorate your property with the `DisplayFormatAttribute`

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt}")]
public DateTime Received { get; set; }
```

Comment: if this solved your problem, you may accept it by clicking the tick icon of this answer, ^^

Answer (score 0):

you can use this attribute to format date as required on the Received property of your model

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{MMMM 0:dd yyyy}")]
```